# How to restrict US State in the Striped Embedded Form?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

I'm using the Stripe Embedded Form. I want to enforce different shipping options/rates depending on which US State the customer has selected. I currently have a custom UI element in which the customer can select their state and this is saved to my backend. I'd like to pass this down to the Embedded Form but because it's an iFrame I can't do this with JS.

I know this is possible for countries using `allowed_countries`, but there seems to be no way of doing this for US States.

Here's my code for creating the checkout session:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  ui_mode: 'embedded',
  line_items,
  mode: 'payment',
  automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: [country],
  },
  shipping_options: [...shipping_options],
  return_url: `${process.env.UI_DOMAIN}/order-confirmation?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
  metadata: {
    ...productMetadata,
  },
});
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this via Embedded Form functionality? Maybe a hack?

Cheers!

Comment: While you already have the customer state, you know what exact Shipping Rate you want to apply to them. Why don't you just specify that only one Shipping Rates into the `shipping_options` when creating the Checkout Session on backend, even before rendering in the frontend? Not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: @orakaro The problem is that the customer might then pick a US State with a cheaper shipping rate on my custom UI element and then pick their actual US State on the stripe form. In effect finding a hack to get cheaper shipping.